# Problema en urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

[image: Imagen del error]

**urls.py**

```
#home/urls.py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home.views import homePageView, dashboardPageView, userPageView, CoinsPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    re_path('activate/(?P<code_>[a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/(?P<email_>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', homePageView.activate, name='activate'),
    path('dashboard/', dashboardPageView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('dashboard/user/', userPageView.as_view(), name='userprofile'),
    re_path('auth/(?P<code_>[a-zA-Z0-9]{12})/(?P<email_>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', homePageView.autenticate, name='autenticate'),
    path('actualice/$', CoinsPageView.actualice, name="actualice")
]
```

¿Por qué me da ese error, si lo tengo definido en mi urls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que quitarle el '$' al final de la url (es django 2.)

```
path('actualice/', CoinsPageView.actualice, name="actualice")
```